# Is Entity Framework caching my value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am attempting to update an entity in EF code first.

I run this code when a button is clicked

```
bool result
if (hasPrivilege == true)result = userManager.RemoveUserPrivilege(Username, privilege, out errors);
else result = userManager.GiveUserPrivilege(Username, privilege, out errors);
```

I then check if the method succeeded and update my list of privileges so that it show the new value.

```
if (result == false) txtBlkErrorMessages.Text = string.Join("\n", errors);
else
{
       privilegeCache = privileges.GetAll(int.MaxValue).Where(prv => prv.Username == Username).OrderBy(prv => prv.PrivilegeName).ToList();
       DisplayInDataGid();
}
```

The problem is that the first part successfully updates the database (I have put a break point and run a query against the database. however the second part still retrieves the previous value.

for example if I select a privilege that is true and I click the button it should remove the privilege and then show that the privilege is false immediately, however it simply shows that it is true.

if I close the window then open it again the value shows the new one.

I have tried setting the privilgeCache object to null then getting the privileges. no joy.

the entity class for this is here:

> ```
> public sealed class UserPrivilege
> {
>     /// <summary>
>     /// PRIMARY KEY -> THE NAME OF THE USER
>     /// MUST BE BETWEEN 5 and 30 CHARACTERS AND IS A REQUIRED FIELD
>     /// </summary>
>     [Key, Column(Order = 0), Required, StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 5), Display(Name = "Username")]
>     public string Username { get; set; }
>
>     /// <summary>
>     /// PRIMARY KEY -> THE NAME OF THE PRIVILEGE
>     /// MUST BE BETWEEN 5 and 30 CHARACTERS AND IS A REQUIRED FIELD
>     /// </summary>
>     [Key, Column(Order = 1), Required, StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 5), Display(Name = "Privilege Name")]
>     public string PrivilegeName { get; set; }
>
>     /// <summary>
>     /// WHETHER THE USERNAME HOLDS THE PRIVILEGE OR NOT
>     /// </summary>
>     [Required, Display(Name = "Holds Privilege")]
>     public bool HoldsPrivilege { get; set; }
> ```
>
> }

The code which updates the database is here:

```
        try
        {
            userPrivilegeRepository.UpdateUserPrivilege(username, privilege, hasPrivilege);

            logger.WriteLog(LogTitle.UserPrivilegeUpdated, LogLevels.Information, LogData);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errors.Add(string.Format(ErrorMessages.ErrorOccured, "Updating a user privilege"));
            logger.WriteLog(LogTitle.ExceptionThrown, LogLevels.Critical, LogData, ex);
            return false;
        }
```

finally the repository code for the update method is:

```
public bool UpdateUserPrivilege(string username, string privilege, bool hasPrivilege)
{
    //GET THE ACCOUNT
    UserPrivilege acct = GetByKeys(new string[] { username, privilege });

    //IF AN ACCOUNT WAS FOUND
    if (acct != null)
    {
        //UPDATE THE FIELDS
        acct.HoldsPrivilege = hasPrivilege;
    }

    bool success = (Database.SaveChanges() > 0);

    //SAVE THE CHANGES
    return success;
}
```

I have a feeling that it is one of two things:

1. EF is caching the value somewhere, if so how do I clear the cache?
2. I had an issue a while ago with the EF designer is visual studio where the keys of the entity mucked stuff up, but I cant see how I could safely change the keys on this entity.

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2013
- C# 4.5
- MYSQL database

I hope someone can help!

Comment: Your issue might be related to DB context management. Can you add the code dealing with Database creation (from (Database.SaveChanges() > 0);). How the privileges list is populated/comes (from in privilegeCache = privileges.GetAll(int.MaxValue)...)?

Comment: I use a generic base repository for this method: -- :          
                                                                                     public virtual IList<Entity> GetAll(int numToGet)
        {
            return Database.Set<Entity>().Take(numToGet).ToList();
        }   and the entity type is UserPrivilege

Comment: Ok and do not forget about Can you add the code dealing with the Database property (from (Database.SaveChanges() > 0)? ;)